# Calling a function from a dictionary, dictionary in imported settings file

Tags: python

So I have a dictionary with a bunch of names that I use to call functions. It works fine, but I prefer to put it in my settings file. If I do so, though, I will get errors from the settings file saying that there are no functions by that name(even though I'm not calling them at the time). Any workarounds?

```
def callfunct(id, time):
    #stuff here
def callotherfunct(id, time):
    #stuff here
dict = {"blah blah": callfunct, "blah blah blah": callfunct, "otherblah": callotherfunct}
dict[str(nameid)](id, time)
```

Hope this makes sense. Also open to other ideas, but basically I have about 50 iterations of these definitions and unique names that are passed by nameid that need to call specific functions, so that's why I do it the way I do, so that I can add new names quickly. It would obviously be even quicker if I could get the dictionary into the settings file seamlessly as well.

Comment: this works fine for me, what errors are you getting?

Comment: the guy below answered, but if you take the dict = {} and put it in a settings.py and then import it to the main, the settings.py will give off errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try

```
def f_one(id, time):
    pass

def f_two(id, time):
    pass

d = {"blah blah":"f_one", "blah blah blah":"f_one", "otherblah","f_two"
locals()[d[str(nameid)]](id, time)
```

(replacing the dictionary initialization with just loading the config file with the string name of the functions you want to call), does that work?

If not, there needs to be a little more info: What does the config file look like, and how are you loading it?

I'm guessing the reason that the config file part isn't working is that you're trying to reference the functions directly from the config file, which shouldn't work. This is using whatever's stored in the config file and looking it up in the `locals()` dictionary (if you're in a function, you'll have to use `globals()` instead)

Comment: Thanks! What specifically is causing your function call to not return "<type 'exceptions.TypeError'> ("'str' object is not callable",)" ?? I assume it is either locals() or the extra brackets around [d[str..]], but I want to look into it for future reference

Comment: You were just getting back a string that was the name of the function you wanted. `locals` lets you look that up in the current scope. `globals` lets you look it up in the current module scope.

Comment: I should clarify that those functions return a dictionary from variable name to variable value.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialise the dictionary with the looked up function only when you attempt to access it:

```
d = {}
d.setdefault('func1', globals()['func1'])()
```